# Cors error between front-and backend in a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, express, docker-compose

I have a problem when trying to connect my vue.js frontend and express.js backend.
I get the following cors error when trying to make the following api call: `api:5000/subscriptions/product`, if I add http:// in front of it, it doesn't find the host

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api:5000/subscriptions/product' from origin
'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
are only supported for protocol schemes:
http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https
```

I run my containers in the follwing docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:

  db:
    image: rafaelbackx.azurecr.io/resto-database
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ...
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "databasevolume:/var/lib/mysql"

  api:
    image: rafaelbackx.azurecr.io/resto-api
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
    environment:
      STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: ...
      PORT: 5000
      HOST: db
      USER: root
      DATABASE: resto
      PASSWORD: ...
      FRONT_END_URL: localhost:3000
      ADMIN_EMAIL: ...
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"

  frontend:
    image: rafaelbackx.azurecr.io/resto-frontend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      VITE_API_URL: api:5000
      port: 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
volumes:
  databasevolume:
```

You can ignore the front_end_url field in the api service (it is used for a link in an email)
Because apparently you cannot use environment variables in vue.js application through docker I had to manually replace the VITE_API_URL in all the js files (I found this solution by googling environment variables in vue.js, and apparently this is done frequently) however since I use the same method to let the backend communicate with the database and it doesnt work for the frontend I assume the error comes from the manual replacement.
this is the dockerfile for my frontend:

```
 from node:16
ENV port=8080
copy package*.json ./
run npm install
run npm install -g http-server
copy . .
run npm run build
# Copy entrypoint script as /entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

# Grant Linux permissions and run entrypoint script
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
# cmd http-server -p $port dist/
```

and this is the entrypoint.sh script:
note that I do put " around the URL, this is because otherwise javascript would complain that the syntax was incorrect as it thought it was a variable.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ROOT_DIR=./dist
ls $ROOT_DIR
URL="'$VITE_API_URL'"
echo $URL
echo "Replacing env constants in JS"
for file in $(find $ROOT_DIR -type f -name \*.js);
do
  echo "Processing $file ...";

  sed -i "s|VITE_API_URL|$URL|g" $file

done
http-server -p $port dist/
```

The cors problem only appeared when I started with docker, before everything worked

```js
import express, { Request, Response, Application } from "express"
import { config } from 'dotenv'
import cors from 'cors'

...

const app : Application = express()

...

app.use(cors())
```

backend docker file:

```
from node:16
copy package*.json ./
run npm install
copy . ./
cmd npm start
```

UPDATE:
I launched an interactive shell to the frontend container and used curl to replicate the http request made and it worked flawless

I used the following command: `docker exec -ti bd080341212d /bin/bash` to get the shell (after docker-compose up, the id is the container-id from the frontend container) and with curl I got the expected result

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What does your backend server.js/app.js code where you initialize the express server look like? Have you installed `cors`?

Comment: yes I use the cors package `app.use(cors())`

Comment: Could you add your backend dockerfile?